# On a 2013 Dodge Caravan is there a way to turn the flexplate without turning the crankshaft?

Tags: dodge, crankshaft, caravan

On a 2013 Dodge Caravan is there a way to turn the flexplate without turning the crankshaft?

In other words is there a seal or bearing that if bad will allow the flexplate to turn freely?

Answer (score 1):

As you use the term flexplate, I assume that it is an automatic.

If the flexplate can turn independantly of the engine then the bolts fixing it have broken or come out or the centre has sheared.